# Singleton design pattern

Tags: php, beginner, object-oriented, singleton, static

I am a beginner in PHP-OOP and design patterns. I have got this basic piece of code in [Singleton Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203336/creating-the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php5) and I changed it in order to understand its behavior. I can see that it works as expected.

However, it is not clear for me exactly how it works. Can anyone explain me? So it is working! My doubt is "Whis `$inst` is not always null in the `if` since I am defining it `null` before entering the `if`"?

```
<?php

final class UserFactory // "final" prevents child classes from overriding a method by prefixing the definition
{
    private $state=1;

    /**
     * Call this method to get singleton
     *
     * @return UserFactory
     */
    public static function Instance()
    {
        static $inst = null;
        if ($inst === null) {
            $inst = new UserFactory();
        }
        return $inst;
    }

    private function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function addToState(){
        $this->state=$this->state+1;
    }
    public function getState(){
        return $this->state;
    }
}

// $myFactory=new UserFactory(); //Throws an error

$myFactory=UserFactory::Instance();
print_r($myFactory);

echo "<br>";
echo 'myState: '.$myFactory->getState()."<br>";

$myFactory->addToState();

echo 'myState: '.$myFactory->getState()."<br>";

$myFactory2=UserFactory::Instance();
print_r($myFactory2);



?>
```

The output is:

```
UserFactory Object ( [state:UserFactory:private] => 1 )
myState: 1
myState: 2
UserFactory Object ( [state:UserFactory:private] => 2 ) UserFactory Object ( [state:UserFactory:private] => 2 )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how the [static](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) keyword works.

The first time it is encountered for a specific variable in the method it defines the `$inst` variable as `null`, then checks to see if it is `null` (it is :p) and then sets it to a new object of that class.

The second time, the static definition isn't used because the static variable has already been defined. It then checks to see if it is `null`, it isn't, it has already been set to a new object of the class, so it skips the if and returns the object.

Answer (score 6):

You're asking a rather specific coding question, and not actually for your code to be reviewed. However, I'm going to, because if you want to learn OOP, you might aswell learn what *not* to do.

Your basic question is answered [in the static-tag wiki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/static/info) which, *cough* I wrote *cough*.
Be that as it may, your singleton implementation still has a few omissions:

- You can't safely add a second static method
- I can still clone the instance
- `$state` is an unreliable variable
- Singletons in PHP are pointless, untestable, anti-patterns. Don't use them
- Choose: OO or globals, don't serve globals in an OO sauce

*Second static method:*
If I add a second static method, that may require access to a non-static method (`public static getCurrentState() { /* check if there's an instance already, call getState on that instsance or return 0 */ }` for example), that method won't have access to the `$inst` variable.
Generally, singletons have a *static property* that holds an instance:

```
class Singleton
{
    private static $inst = null;
    private $state = null;//<-- why 1?

    private function __construct()
    {
        $this->state = 0;
    }
    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (static::$inst === null)
        {
            static::$inst = new Singleton();
        }
        static::$inst->state += 1;//update refcount here
        return static::$inst;
    }
    public static function getStateCount()
    {
        if (static::$inst === null)
            return 0;
        static::$inst->state;//no need to call a getter, we're in the right scope for private access
    }
}
```

Great, so now all static (and non-static) methods have access to the `$inst` property, and we can use that variable in all methods. Since all methods will, by definition, be defined *within the class*, they have access to private properties anyway, so we don't need getters and setters. We can just access the properties directly (which is faster).

*Cloning a singleton shouldn't be possible*
Now imagine your object actually does something even mildly important. For example, a Singleton is sometimes (ab-)used for DB connections, what would be the result of doing this:

```
$db = Singleton::getInstance();//as you'd expect $db is now an object
$clone = clone $db;//You're in trouble!
```

That's why Singletons often implement the magic `__clone` method (along with other magic methods):

```
public function __clone()
{//make singleton un-clonable
    return false;
    //or even:
    throw new RuntimeException('You cannot clone a singleton, hooligan!');
}
```

Do the same for `__toString`, `__sleep` and other magic methods.
Ok, now we've sorted that out, onwards:

*`$state` is unreliable:*
Because `$state` can't be decremented (or no code to decrement it is provided), and because your singleton is clone-able, the value of `$state` isn't guaranteed to be shared between all instances. Solving the clone issue addresses this, as does making the property `static`, too. But really, as I'm going to explain now: *avoid `static` whenever you can*.

*Singleton and PHP is pointless:*
PHP is, essentially, stateless. `Static` and singletons along with it enable you to persist something, to retain a state. But retaining state in a stateless environment is like placing an empty bottle in a fridge: it still won't give you something cool to drink.

Each request that executes your code starts with a blank slate, and your singleton will be re-initialized. Couple that to the fact that static properties and methods are (marginally) slower, and you end up with pointless overhead.
If you don't want a second instance of class X, *don't create a second instance*. Think when writing code, don't write code that sort of *fixes* coding errors on your part.

Testing a singleton is a nightmare, google *"PHP test singleton"* and read a few articles. It's a well documented downside that will soon have you steer clear of this anti-pattern.

*Globals in OO drag*
Singletons (and basically all statics), then, what do they do: They couple state (data, variables) and functionality (in the form of methods) together, without the safety and flexibility of an actual instance.
A static method actually *is* a global function, that calls on some data (in the form of static properties it can access) to do its job. That's what makes code that uses a lot of `static`'s harder to maintain and understand.

If you want functionality that requires, for example, a DB connection: use an object that does just that. It's safer, you know that if something fails where to look and it is more flexible, simply because *you can pass an instance to other methods/functions as an argument*.

If you use `ClassName::staticMethod()`, you're writing code that looks OO, but could just aswell be written like this: `globalFunction($dbConnection, $param);`.
Whereas *true* OO code would look like this:

```
$service->queryUsers($dbInstance, $userStatus);
```

The `queryUsers` method could look like this, then:

```
public function queryUsers(DBConnection $db, $status = self::USER_ACTIVE)
{
    if (!in_array($status, $this->acceptedStatusses)
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid user-status');

    return $db->query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE userStatus = '.$status)
        ->fetchResults();
}
```